# How to post bulk to elastic search using python?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, kibana

I have to post some information to elastic search using python. My info looks like

```
{  "index": {"_type": "TestSuiteReport","_index": "testsuite"}}{"Driver Name": "","Run Mode": "","TestSuite_Starttime": "2016-10-0T14:20:09","TestSuite Link": "2016-10-20T14:20:09","Number Of Tests Passed": 491}
```

I was using curl for posting the data to my search server using the command

```
Curl -i -X PUT -k "http://serverip:5601/_bulk" --data-binary @filelocation.
```

Can somebody help me finding alternative way to implement this in python ?

Answer (score 2):

Read the json data from your file. Use requests python library to post the json to your server

```
import requests
data = open('yourfile').read()
url = "http://serverip:5601/_bulk"
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Note that 5601 is the kibana port, so it has to be 9200 if you want to store directly to es.

Comment: Not sure if something changed, but this throws 406
   '{"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}'

Answer (score -1):

I found python useful for this scenario and example to that is shared here. tryolabs.com/blog/2015/02/17/python-elasticsearch-first-step‌​s. This could send your single json doc to elasticsearch.